# "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed" при вызове file_get_contents

Tags: php

Иногда выскакивает:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://109.234.156.253/prison/universal.php?&key=6c760e3beb701f54b53&method=getAllBuildingsRewards&user=4297099) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in O:\home\test1.ru\www\getprib.php on line 7

Как сделать, чтобы вместо этого  выскакивало сообщение: Ошибка сервера

Вот мой код

```
 $get = file_get_contents('http://109.234.156.253/prison/universal.php?&key='.$myrow['PRCLauth'].'&method=getAllBuildingsRewards&user='.$myrow['PRCLid']);
preg_match_all("/<money>(.*?)<\/money>/",$get,$matches);
$cd1 = $matches[1][0];
echo $cd1;
```

Comment: C php.net:
`file_get_contents() возвращает содержимое файла в строке, начиная с указанного смещения offset и до maxlen байт. В случае неудачи, file_get_contents() вернёт FALSE.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потестируй вот это:

```
@file_get_contents('http://google.ru'); 
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

Как видишь, в переменной `$http_response_header` содержатся заголовки сервера. Тебе остается выбрать нужный заголовок, в котором содержится статус и прогнать через функцию, которая определяет статус.

Comment: Эммм?      ))))

Comment: @Vlmake что не понятно? С массивами, я думаю, работать вы умеете. С регуляркой, как я вижу, тоже знакомы. В чем у вас возникают сложности?

Comment: Я знаю как применять, но не знаю что значить что, ну точнее что так называется.

Comment: примерно так:

 @file_get_contents('http://109.234.156.253'); 
 $status = substr($http_response_header[0], 9, 3);

 switch ($status) {
  case 200:
   echo "all ok";
   break;
  case 404:
   echo "page not found";
   break;
  case 403:
   echo "access denied";
   break;
  case 500:
   echo "server error";
   break;
 }

Comment: ну да, но всё равно 
Warning: file_get_contents(http://109.234.156.253/prison/universal.php?&key=653&method=getAllBuildingsRewards&user=1) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in O:\home\test1.ru\www\getprib.php on line 7
server error

Answer (score 1):

```
if($get==FALSE)
echo "Ошибка сервера";
//а что мудрить то?
```

Comment: ну да он выводит эту надпись, но выше  Warning: file_get_contents(http://109.234.156.253/prison/universal.php?&key=6d&method=getAllBuildingsRewards&user=1) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in O:\home\test1.ru\www\getprib.php on line 7

Comment: если надо, чтоб не выскакивал ворнинг (если я правильно понял (?)), то нужна собачка перед file_get_contents:
$get = @file_get_contents

Comment: Вот это я и хотел большое спасибо

Comment: @Vlmake это собачка есть во всех сообщениях :) Я думал, вы о ней знаете.

Comment: просто никто не понял, что нужно человеку

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    $get = @file_get_contents($url);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    throw new Exception ('Ошибка сервера');
}
```

Comment: Вы проверяли?

Comment: Я? Да, но не робит.